# Error: with apollo-codegen package while working on AWS amplify

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am following [this](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/android/start?ref=amplify-android-btn) to build an app using AWS cloud. Whenever I try to build the app using Android studio, I am getting the following error:

`Unable to delete file: C:\Users\Lenovo\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication3\app\build\apollo-codegen\node_modules\apollo-codegen\package.json`

Does it have anything to do with permissions?

I have searched it on internet but nothing was found. 
Thank you in advance.

Android studio version: 3
API level : 28

Comment: I think it's not related to AWS. By the log, it is clearly saying trying to delete the file but doesn't have permissions. Are you using different user than administrator ?

Comment: hi @jagriti welcome to stackoverflow, please mention more details like when this error occur, on what line or on what step this error occured

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have the same problem. The only solution I have so far is to close then reopen Android Studio. The problem is: I have to do that each time I want to build my project. So if anyone comes up with a better solution, I'm interested.

Answer (score 0):

Were you trying to create a Android project and a React Native project in the same folder?

node_modules and apollo-codegen are things that you should see in a React Native project. If you have been playing around with both I would recommend trying to start again in an empty folder.

Answer (score 0):

Update Android studio to version 3.4.2 (or greater), it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dismiss the app in the emulator or the device in order to be deleted.